# How to rotate rectangle without it being cropped

Tags: rotation, crop, snap.svg

I created a rectangle 1.5 inches x 1.5 inches and add a border around the outside, when I rotate it 45 degrees the corners get cropped as shown below.  How do I rotate something like this without it being cropped?

[image: Before Rotation]

[image: After Rotation]

I tested rotating this SVG shape with Snap and with css.  I get very different results between the two.  With the app I am building the shape can be rotated from 0-359 degrees.  Here is what they shape looks like between the 2.  The shape looks nice rotated with Snap but when put in a div and rotated with CSS it looks REALLY bad.  So I guess I am going to need to figure out something wit a larger SVG area and center the shape in that area, the only issue is that I have about 80 different blocks of various shapes and sizes.

[image: SVG shape rotated with Snap]
[image: SVG shape rotated with CSS]

Comment: Other than the knee-jerk response of "make the outer image root-two times as large"?

Comment: I had thought about that but then I would have the SVG centered in that area because if it was just at the top left I would still lose the corners on the left and top when rotated.  Not really ideal.  Maybe put the SVG into a div and rotate the div using jQuery?

Comment: Why isn't it ideal to centre it, it seems quite sensible to have an area big enough for an object to rotate in ? It depends what you are trying to do, if its in isolation, then just use a div, or a css transform or something, you don't need Snap at all then. If you need Snap for other stuff thats going on, centre it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate the square, make sure the area you're trying to rotate it in has 1.4 x the length of the square. Basically, you want space equal to the longest diagonal in the bounding box of your shape (a square is the simplest, of course).

Doing this same thing in CSS, you've got the browser taking care of compositing the images for  you, and you don't have the explicit bounding area of the  element. If you're doing it within SVG, you have that limitation - so just accomodate it.